# Cell colorization

Tags: javascript, odoo, odoo-8

There is an odoo system with a timesheet module (self-made) in it. I want to color the weekends cells in there. Some code examples below:

```
openerp.Tabel = function (instance) {
   instance.web.list.columns.add('field.mywidget', 'instance.Tabel.mywidget');
   instance.Tabel.mywidget = instance.web.list.Column.extend({
                         ...
   _format: function (row_data, options) {
      res = this._super.apply(this, arguments);
      var startDate = row_data['time_start_s'].value;
      if (startDate.length>0){
      //Get massive dd.mm.yyyy
      var arr = startDate.split('-');
      var d = new Date(arr[0],arr[1]-1,arr[2]);
      //Get current number of month. From field name delete all chars.
      var number = this.name.replace(/[A-Za-z]/g, "") - 1;
      d.setDate(  d.getDate()+ number );
      if ( d.getDay()==0 || d.getDay()==6)
         if (res.length>0)
            return "<div class=\"oe_readonly\" style=\" color:#4d394b; background:#eadee0;  \" >" + res+"</div>";
         else
            return "<div  class=\"oe_readonly\" style=\" color:#4d394b; background:#eadee0;  \" > &nbsp;&nbsp;</div>";
   }
    return res;
   },
});
```

But this colors cells not entirely. Screenshot below:
[image: timesheet table cells]

Is there any way to fix it? Any advises, as always, are highly appreciated.

Comment: Only the div is being accessed and therefore the colour applied. You need a way to style the actual td - not the div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved via using width and height parameters.

```
if ( d.getDay()==0 || d.getDay()==6)
                    if (res.length>0)
                        return "<div class=\"oe_readonly\" style=\" color:#4d394b; background:#a79ca6; width: 100%; height: 100%;  \" >" + res+"</div>";
                    else
                        return "<div  class=\"oe_readonly\" style=\" color:#4d394b; background:#a79ca6; width: 100%; height: 100%;  \" > &nbsp;&nbsp;</div>";
}
return res;
}
```

+

```
padding: 0px 0px;
```

in .css file.

Answer (score 1):

Try using CSS styles instead.  You can VERY EASILY style a column using CSS:

`td:nth-child(1) { background-color: #5555FF }`

This styles the first column.